# Insert question

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    SqlConnection con;
    DataSet dsl;
    SqlDataAdapter da;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection();
        dsl = new DataSet();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\tbl.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

        con.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * From tbl_fb";
        //string sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_fb (Ime) VALUES ('aaa3')";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        da.Fill(dsl, "fb");

        SqlCommandBuilder cb;
        cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

        DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["fb"].NewRow();
        dRow[1] = "some text";
        dsl.Tables["fb"].Rows.Add(dRow);

        da.Update(dsl, "fb");
    }
}
```

This code, supposed to save the "aaa3" string to 'Ime' row. Or the "some text" string to row[1](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p10.html) (which is Ime - second row).

But it isn't working. Anyone knows why.

I tried this using [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p10.html).

Thanks.

Comment: any errors? exceptions? have you run a trace, what's happening? all information that is more useful than "but it isnt working".

Comment: no errors, no exceptions, all seems to be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He would still need to execute the command object. However the second bit looks odd...

replace the fb with tbl_fb like :

```
DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["tbl_fb"].NewRow();
dRow[1] = "some text";             
dsl.Tables["tbl_fb"].Rows.Add(dRow);              
da.Update(dsl, "tbl_fb");
```

Comment: And i get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error within the first line --> "DataRow dRow = dsl.Tables["tbl_fb"].NewRow();"
I think i'll have to use the different tactic :P

Ty for help

Answer (score 1):

When you creating DataAdapter object like you did, only SelectCommand property is set. There are no UpdateCommand or InsertCommand setuped in you DataAdapter object for updating data in database.
do this:

```
da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdateQuary)
da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdateQuary)
```